# How to make a mail sender application approved as secure by Gmail?

Tags: security, gmail, jakarta-mail

I develop an application which has to send emails (by JavaMail) through an external mail server, which can be Gmail too.
First I faced a credentinal error, but it came out that cause of the problem was that Gmail refuses the connection from a less secure application by default. When I enabled this option, the connection worked.

My question is: what should I do to let Google accept the application as a secure one?
My goal is to use the program without setting of the "allow insecure applications" option in.

Is there a validation process at Google to accept an applicaton as secure?
If not, what I need to implement in the sw to meet the requirements?

I've found similar question, but there was only one answer with a guess, instead of a proved solution.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm able to tell, Google's definition of "less secure app" is "an app that doesn't use [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)". So, if you want your app to be able to use GMail without the whole "less secure app" thing frightening away your customers, you're going to need to implement OAuth.